# Does WMI data get refreshed while OS is running?

Tags: window, wmi, wmi-query, wmi-service

I have a question about Windows Management Interface data (WMI).

I know this data gets populated at the boot time. When OS keeps running without powering cycle the machine, does this WMI data ever get refreshed?

Thanks!

Comment: I ran some tests and found WMI does get refreshed by the OS automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It does get refreshed by the OS automatically. But if you are in doubt and looking for high precision. Use `WbemScripting.SWbemRefresher` if you are using VB. This will refresh the data and provide you latest results.

Please refer [Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393026(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.